# gvim text select with mouse misses last character

Tags: gvim

In gvim, if I click on a character and drag the mouse *backwards* in the text, I get a highlighted text selection.  However, the actual character I click on, which I expect to be the last character in my selection, is not included.  If I click on a character and drag the mouse forwards, I don't have a problem.  Is there any way to make gvim include the last character when selecting by dragging backwards, just as in any any other text editor, such as Notepad?  Confirmation that others see the same behaviour would also be useful.

I appreciate one solution would be 'drag forwards not backwards'.  However, this habit is highly ingrained - I don't even know I'm doing it until some time later I notice I have cut and pasted a block without the last character.  I'd rather change the behaviour of the software.

I am running gvim 7.3 on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
:set sel=inclusive
```

Comment: That does exactly what I want.  Thank-you!!